# HTML tags automatically removed from node body field in Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I want to output full node body code in Views, but HTML tags get automatically stripped. The problem is that "Strip HTML tags" check box isn't checked.

So, instead of e.g.:

```
<p>Example</p>
```

I get:

```
Example
```

Edit: I see that I didn't explain my problem well. What I want to get aren't e. g. 5 paragraphs. I want to get the code displayed. E. g.:

```
<p>Paragraph1</p>
<p>Paragraph2</p>
<p>Paragraph3</p>
```

Instead of:

```
Paragraph1
Paragraph2
Paragraph3
```

The purpose is to export the code to import these nodes in another installation.

Comment: How are you planning on exporting/importing the nodes?

Comment: @HaleFx Export through views data export module and import through feeds. Everything works perfectly except this part. And this part is unfortunately very important.

Comment: And you're sure that the HTML tags aren't making it over to Feeds? You wouldn't be able to see them in the Views preview because your browser would render them on the page.

There are a lot of HTML issues in Feeds. http://drupal.org/project/issues/feeds?text=html&status=All

Comment: @HaleFX They are making it to Feeds, that's not the problem. If I manually enter HTML tags in a test CSV file, they are imported without any problems. What bothers me is that when Node Body field is selected in Views, the Views display it as if it were a normal node (with all of the paragraphs, headings etc. parsed). I want to avoid that part and make Views display only the HTML code.

Comment: You're actually getting "only the HTML code". Your browser is rendering it like it does with all other HTML (hiding the tags from you). Feeds isn't a browser, though, so it wouldn't have a problem with that.

It sounds like your problem might actually be the Views data export module.

Comment: Probably it is, because XML format seems to have paragraph tags. I'll probably have to wait for the next releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the text format of the node's body field set to strip `<p>` tags before the content even gets into Views. Edit one of the affected nodes, make sure that the text format is not set to "Plain text", and make sure that `<p>` is in the list of "Allowed HTML tags".

(For Drupal7) If it isn't in the list, go to Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring and click on Text Formats (/admin/config/content/formats). Click "configure" for the text format you want to change. Add `<p>` to the list of "Allowed HTML tags" in the "Filter settings". Or you could set up a new text format that doesn't limit the allowed HTML tags.

(For Drupal6) Go to /admin/settings/filters, click "configure" for the text format you want to change then click its "Configure" tab.

If you want to display the body field's HTML, the HTML needs to be "escaped" so that the browser doesn't render it. The only way I know to do this would be to set the text format of each node to "Plain text" and then change your Views Field Formatter to "Default".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question with better explanation hopefully. The tags are there, but Drupal takes them into account and displays the text accordingly. I want to have a display with the code visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the output with HTML tags, you can do two things:

1. Build a normal view and then copy/paste the HTML code from View source option or from Firebug
2. Use the patch for Views data export module posted here: http://drupal.org/node/1224894. That way you can export fields with HTML tags included.